# Инкапсуляция в наследовании Python

Tags: python, наследование, инкапсуляция

Всем привет. Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private_attribute = 42

class Child(Parent):
    def get_private_attribute(self):
        return self.__private_attribute
        
child = Child()
print(child.get_private_attribute())
```

Не могу получить атрибут. Понимаю, что это происходит из-за дандера перед `private`, который добавляет имя класса, но как быть с инкапсуляцией в случае, когда у меня дочерний класс должен обращаться к таким переменным? Использовать одинарное подчёркивание? Или работа с "закрытыми" методами через дочерний класс - это вообще ошибка?

В различных справочниках по такой теме для Python ничего не нашёл, пишут про обычное наследование, с которым проблем не возникает

Comment: Если вы сделали переменную приватной, то из этого напрямую следует, что дочерний класс НЕ должен обращаться к таким переменным. Если всё-таки должен, то для этого есть то самое одинарное подчёркивание

Comment: @andreymal Большое спасибо, помогли разобраться